# Find the voltage, Vx, and current, Ix

Tags: circuit-analysis

Question: [image]

I was asked to use mesh analysis to find the Vx and Ix. 
 I tried that out but got stuck see my working here.

please, can someone help show me where I'm getting wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From your comments I assume you are unsure about how to solve the last two equations.
You have two equations and two variables. We have several tricks for solving in this situation.

First trick (recommended): 
Solve for one variable in terms of the other, and plug that into the other equation.
Here is a nice [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_kMqvjLq9g) that explains how to do it ([clicky](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_kMqvjLq9g)).

Second trick:
Use a matrix to solve for both variables at once (in a manner of speaking).

Doing either of these will give you the current Ix. Once you have that you can use it and the appropriate resistor value (v = IR) to get the value of Vx.

I don't want to work the problem for you, but if you get the wrong answer I would suggest revisiting your two initial mesh equations.

Comment: can you confirm
 if my meshing equations are correct?

Comment: Yes, they are correct as in they will give you the right answer. But your second loop does not match the assumed the polarity of the  4k resistor (unless I am going crazy). Your final answer will still be the same, because the 4k polarity does not show up in any other equations. It does not matter what the polarity is, as long as you stay consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Your equations are correct, and as the other answer correctly points out, you need to solve the final equations via simultaneous equations or matrix algebra.